# What is wrong with this python source code

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

when I execute this source code with: 1 2 3 4

```
population = int(input()).split()
def get_deviation(population):
    average = float(sum(population))/float(population)
    s = 0
    for n in population:
        s += float((n-average)**2)

    deviation = float(s**0.5)    
    print(deviation)

    get_deviation(population)
```

I get this error:

```
population = int(input()).split()
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'
```

Comment: Just *think* about the order in which your code is doing things...

Comment: `population = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: when I use I get:
average = float(sum(population))/float(population)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Think about what you're doing there. You called `float` on `population`, when `population` is a list. I think you want the number of elements in `population`, instead

Comment: just in case: python has a built-in statistics module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#module-statistics

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I wanted to implemented manually, it is a part of the challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> average = float(sum(population))/float(population)
> ```

This line means nothing. You can't divide a number by a list.

Try

```
average = float(sum(population))/float(len(population))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to divide by `len(population)`; as mentioned above `float(population)` is a list...

and you forgot to divide your deviation by that. this should work (but better double-check!)

```
from math import sqrt

# population = int(input()).split()
population = (1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 3.25, 4.75)

def get_deviation(population):
    N = float(len(population))
    average = sum(population)/N
    deviation = sqrt(sum((n-average)**2 for n in population)/N)

    return average, deviation


avg, dev = get_deviation(population)
print(avg, dev)
```